# Trying to add "Free Text Box" to a web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, freetextbox

So, I added a FTB by using a Formview that connects the database to the webpage.

When I tried to run the page and use the FTB, I was greeted with the following message:

"FreeTextBox has not been correctly installed. To install FreeTextBox either:
(1) add a reference to FtbWebResource.axd in web.config:

```
    <system.web>
<httpHandlers>
<add verb="GET"
path="FtbWebResource.axd"
type="FreeTextBoxControls.AssemblyResourceHandler, FreeTextBox" />
</httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

(2) Save the FreeTextBox image and javascript files to a location on your website and set up FreeTextBox as follows

```
<FTB:FreeTextBox id="FreeTextBox1" SupportFolder="ftbfileslocation" JavaScriptLocation="ExternalFile" ButtonImagesLocation="ExternalFile" ToolbarImagesLocation="ExternalFile" ButtonImagesLocation="ExternalFile" runat="server" />"
```

I have already gone to the FTB download site and acquired the DLL. I created a bin folder in Visual Studio 2013 Exp and added the DLL to the file.

My web config currently looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\PageContent.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET" 
           path="FtbWebResource.axd" 
           type="FreeTextBoxControls.AssemblyResourceHandler, FreeTextBox"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.DynamicData, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS 7 and above you might want to register it in the handlers section of the System.webServer section.

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
 <handlers>
      <add name="FreeTextBox" path="FtbWebResource.axd" verb="GET" type="FreeTextBoxControls.AssemblyResourceHandler, FreeTextBox" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```